# UIImagePickerController in IOS 7 always showing did receive memory warning

Tags: ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using below code to show custom camera control. When I commented **cameraSetup** method in **viewDidLoad** then app is not receiving any memory warning. Any idea why it's receiving memory warning?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self cameraSetup];
}
- (void)cameraSetup {
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
    [self showImagePickerForSourceTypeInTakePhoto:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
#else
    [self showImagePickerForSourceTypeInTakePhoto:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];

#endif
}

- (void)showImagePickerForSourceTypeInTakePhoto:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
self.imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
self.imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
self.imagePickerController.sourceType = sourceType;
self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
if (sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera){
    self.imagePickerController.showsCameraControls = NO;
    self.overlayView.frame = self.view.frame ;//imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView.frame;
   self.imagePickerController.cameraOverlayView = self.overlayView;
}
[self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

}